# Rressure sensor offset removal

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, offset

I have a pressure sensor that has 200 mV offset. I wanted to remove this offset and double the result (to remove any present noise) so that be able to calibrate the sensor easier. So far I have used a simple op-amp based subtractor circuit. The problem is that if the difference between the two inputs is more than 300 mV, the circuit would work without flaw. If the inputs would be the same, there is an offset of 600 mV in output (While simulation with proteus fails to show this matter, haven't yet simulated the circuit with Cadance Orcade). How can I solve the issue?
Will using rail-to-rail opamp solve the problem? A simple schematic is attached.  [image]

Comment: If it's just calibration why do you want to remove the offset? Just use a better meter than can give you the resolution with the offset.

Comment: @Andyaka Not just the calibration, but removing the noise from sensor to MCU. (some electromagnetic noise is present.)

Comment: What noise? You didn't mention noise in your question. Please adjust your question to define the problem more precisely.

Comment: Removal of noise requires some sort of filtering, not a subtraction of DC voltage.

Comment: The circuit you posted implicitly assumes the output impedance of the pressure transducer is low (i.e. in comparison with R2).  Your values of R2 and R1 are really quite small for this kind of op-amp circuit (e.g. if the inverting input is at 1V and the op-amp output is, say, 8V -- then R1 has 7V across it and 3.5mA which is rather high considering 1/10th or even 1/100th that value would work.  Personally I would scale all your R's up by a factor of 100 or 200, which would boost the input impedance accordingly, and thus not load the transducer like it does now.

Comment: @Atomique Thank you for your comment. Tested 100k ohm resistor, now the opamp output is about 10mv while the inputs are nearly the same. is there any method other than using rail to rail  opamps to even omit this 10mv?